# Changing Foreground color of ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the foreground color of `ComboBoxItem`, however it does not apply, what am I doing wrong? Also I'm trying to change the foreground color of hovers on `ComboBoxItem` which does not work as well.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tab5_2_num"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontSize="13" FontFamily="/WPF;component/Font/#Agency FB" Margin="722,46,406,281" BorderThickness="1,1,1,4" Height="30">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Label x:Name="lblCombo" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="/WPF;component/Font/#Agency FB" FontSize="13" Height="20" />
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="lblCombo" Property="Background" Value="#FFF01F1F"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="lblCombo" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: May I ask how did you know that this is not working? Any particular error message or manifestations?

Comment: Actually i was doing it in reverse, see the @JayZuo answer it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set `Label` in your `ComboBoxItem`'s template, the `Label` set in `DataTemplate` won't work. So please try following code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tab5_2_num" Height="30" BorderThickness="1,1,1,4" FontFamily="/WPF;component/Font/#Agency FB" FontSize="13" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Label x:Name="lblCombo" Content="{Binding}" FontFamily="/WPF;component/Font/#Agency FB" FontSize="13" Foreground="Black" />
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="lblCombo" Property="Background" Value="#FFF01F1F" />
                                <Setter TargetName="lblCombo" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

It should work.

Comment: Worked like a charm, just had to give the Content="{Binding}" to the label blow, thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all I wonder if you see the `Label` content. You may need the following:

```
<Label Content={Binding} ... />
```